# Which one is the correct/preferable form of the word "Word "in the sentence: a word or words

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one is the correct form of the word "Word "in the sentence: word or words

> Can I have a **word** with you?

or

> Can I have **words** with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are fine, although they typically mean different things.

> Can I have **a word** with you?

This means that you are asking to simply ask or tell somebody something.

> Can I have **words** with you?

This is a common expression that implies you are angry with them. By *having words*, you will express your displeasure and, perhaps, indicate what they did wrong and what will happen now.

---

A famous line from the movie [*Robocop*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbnhgi-bW_0) (YouTube clip) is:

> "Come quietly or there will be . . . trouble."

This could be paraphrased as:

> "Come quietly or we will have . . . words."

---

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-words-with-someone):

> **have words with [somebody]**
>
> If one person has words with another, or if two or more people have words, they have a serious discussion or argument, especially because one has complained about the other's behaviour.
>
> *We had words and she stormed out.
>
>   I shall have words with these stupid friends of mine!*

Answer (score 0):

"Can I have a word with you?" is the correct one when asking to speak to someone.

"Can I have words with you?" is wrong - it could even be interpreted as "Can I eat words with you?".

Hope this helped.

Comment: "Eat words"? MacMillan dictionary says "to have words with somebody" means to argue or quarrel with them. --->    https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-exchange-words-with-somebody